# Golang append to a slice of type

Tags: arrays, go, types, append, slice

I am doing an ldap query, and I want to populate the result into a slice. The result looks something like

```
objectClass [top person organizationalPerson user]
cn [user.1]
sn [one]
description [user.1]
givenName [user]
distinguishedName [CN=user.1,OU=random,DC=example,DC=com]
...
```

I am trying to populate it to a map and for that, I created a type.

```
    type keyvalue map[string]interface{}
```

Now I want to create a slice of this type, so that the data would look something like this for multiple users taken

```
objectClass [top person organizationalPerson user]
cn [user.1]
sn [one]
description [user.1]
givenName [user]
distinguishedName [CN=user.1,OU=random,DC=example,DC=com]
...
objectClass [top person organizationalPerson user]
cn [user.2]
sn [one]
description [user.2]
givenName [user]
distinguishedName [CN=user.2,OU=random,DC=example,DC=com]
...
```

For that, I created a slice of the type that I created above.

```
userslice := make([]keyvalue, 1, 1)
```

How will I append each users's parameters into the slice in each iteration?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you create an item of type keyvalue for a user, you append it with userslice = append(userslice, user). Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `keyvalue` instead of `map[string]interface{}` in your code:

```
type keyvalue map[string]interface{}

....

user1 := make(keyvalue)
user1["distinguishedName"] = "[CN=user.1,OU=random,DC=example,DC=com]"
user1["givenName"] = "user"

var userslice []keyvalue
userslice = append(userslice, user1)

fmt.Printf("%#v", userslice)
```